# apache camel webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

I have created endpoint and a route inside of my `camel-context.xml` like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="testEndpoint" address="https://127.0.0.1:443/ws"
            serviceClass="pl.test.ws.testWsImpl"
            wsdlURL="/META-INF/wsdl/testCFService.wsdl"
            endpointName="s:test_Port"
            serviceName="s:testDescriptor"
            xmlns:s = "test.namespace"/>
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
       <route>
         <from uri="direct://start" />
         <to uri="cxf:bean:testEndpoint" />
       </route>
    </camelContext>
```

and then I am trying to call this webservice by creating `ProducerTemplate`

```
@Produce(uri="direct:start")
    ProducerTemplate pt;
```

and sending message into it:

```
pt.send(new Processor() {
  public void process(Exchange exchange_) throws Exception {
    TestRequest test = new TestRequest();
    test.setRequest("hello world");
    exchange_.getIn().setBody(test);
    System.out.println(exchange_.getOut().getBody());
}});
```

I have `WebService` locally up and running so I can see that the request is being send because it is being received, however I don't knew how to handle response.

line `System.out.println(exchange_.getOut().getBody());` is returning `null` value when `WebService` sent `Received` in response.

Can anyone tell me how to process the response from `Exchange` ?

Answer (score 1):

The reply comes from what pt.send returns.

The process method is only for configuring the request method. Not to get the reply. The reply is from what the `pt.send` returns.

```
Exchange reply = pt.send(...)
```

Also mind about OUT vs IN see this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html